# Whst is the maximum viewing angle?

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

While working on a math workbook(it doesn't have solutions), I got stuck on this problem:
Two vehicles, A and B, start at point P and travel east at rates of 10km/h and 30km/h, respectively. An observer at Q, 1 km north of P, is able to observe both vehicles. What is the maximum angle of sight between the observer's view of A and B?
Also, as a hint, the book says "Use the sum and difference identity for tangent functions."
Could anyone explain how I should solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $A$ is a distance $x$ from $P$, $B$ is a distance $3x$. So $\tan PQA=x,\tan PQB=3x$. We want to maximize $\angle BQA=\angle PQB-\angle PQA=\tan^{-1}3x-\tan^{-1}x$. The same value of $x$ will also maximize $\tan BQA=\frac{3x-x}{1+3x^2}$ (using the familiar formula $\tan(X-Y)=\frac{\tan X-\tan Y}{1+\tan X\tan Y}$).

If you know any calculus that is straightforward, just differentiate to find the maximum. Otherwise we show that $\frac{2x}{1+3x^2}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$. Squaring, that is equivalent to $12x^2\le(1+3x^2)^2$ or $9x^4-6x^2+1\ge0$ or $(3x^2-1)^2\ge0$, which is obviously true. It is also obvious that the maximum occurs at $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$.

The maximum angle is given by $\tan^{-1}BQA=\frac{2x}{1+3x^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$, so the maximum angle is $30^o$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem more of physics.

At any time $t$
$$\theta=\tan ^{-1}30t-\tan ^{-1}10t$$

$${d\theta\over dt}={30\over 1+900t^2}-{10\over 1+100t^2}=0$$

$$t={1\over \sqrt{300}}\ hr$$

$$\theta =\tan ^{-1}{30\over \sqrt{300}}-\tan ^{-1}{10\over \sqrt{300}}$$

$$\theta =\tan ^{-1}{3\over \sqrt{3}}-\tan ^{-1}{1\over \sqrt{3}}$$

$$\theta =\tan ^{-1}{\sqrt{3}} -\tan ^{-1}{\sqrt{3}\over 3}$$

$$\theta ={\pi \over 3} -{\pi \over 6}$$

$$\theta ={\pi \over 6}$$